# .net passing data into Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

What's the lightest method to pass data into a Crystal Report in an ASP.NET site?  I've pushed custom collections and datasets.  I have a advanced custom collection and I really need to only pass in two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a fairly lightweight XML doc? Crystal Reports can pull data from pretty much anything

Comment: I don't need to make an actual XML file, do I?  Can I just manually build the XML and pass it into the report?  Would I just pass an XmlDocument object as the DataSource?

Comment: I believe so, in the same way you could push the dataset across.

Comment: I'll have to try this next time.  Thanks!